# Issue using a XML document as a pipeline b/w process in Powershell

Tags: powershell, oop, pipe, pipeline

The Powershell code bellow uses a XML document as a pipeline to share an object between two process. Actually for test propose I run this code in two different Powershell session to see two process.

The property `$logoff_processObj` just works fine. It means that after it is updated in the process 1, it is successfully read and stopped in the process 3.

However, it does not work with the property `$LastUpdate_SheetRange` and I cannot understand why.

When I open the XML file after finish the process 1, I do not see the value set for `$LastUpdate_SheetRange` there.

What is the problem?

```
class XMLpipe 
{
    hidden $pp_path = (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'HPCMpipe.xml')
    hidden [System.Object]$logoff_processObj
    hidden [string]$LastUpdate_SheetRange

    XMLpipe()
    {
        if([System.IO.File]::Exists($this.pp_path))
        {
            $this = Import-Clixml -Path $this.pp_path
        }
    }

    [void]setObj_toXML()
    {
        $this | Export-Clixml -Path $this.pp_path
    }

    [System.Object]getObj_fromXML()
    {
        $this = (Import-Clixml -Path $this.pp_path)
        return $this
    }

    [void]set_processObj($value)
    {
        $this.logoff_processObj = $value
        $this.setObj_toXML()  
    }

    [void]set_LastUpdate_SheetRange($value)
    {
        $this.LastUpdate_SheetRange = $value
        $this.setObj_toXML()
    }

    [System.Object]get_processObj()
    {
        $this = $this.getObj_fromXML()
        return $this.logoff_processObj
    }

    [string]get_LastUpdate_SheetRange()
    {
        $this = $this.getObj_fromXML()
        return $this.LastUpdate_SheetRange
    }

}
```

## Process 1:

```
$myobj = New-Object -TypeName XMLpipe

#This starts a 2nd process
$ProcessObj = Start-Process notepad -PassThru

$myobj.set_processObj($ProcessObj)
$myobj.set_LastUpdate_SheetRange("ABC")
```

## Process 3:

```
$myobj = New-Object -TypeName XMLpipe

#This gets the process object started in the 1st process
$ProcessObj = $myobj.get_processObj()
$LastUpdate_SheetRange = $myobj.get_LastUpdate_SheetRange()

#This stops the 2nd process
$ProcessObj | Stop-Process

Write-Host "ProcessObj: "$ProcessObj
Write-Host "get_LastUpdate_SheetRange: "$LastUpdate_SheetRange
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `[void]` before `set_LastUpdate_SheetRange` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying @Theo. It is.not mandatory in this case. Actually I tested, but it doesn't make any difference. It had `[void]` there before I delete it to test.

Comment: `setObj_toXML` is not working when is called in ´set_LastUpdate_SheetRange´. I have noted that the last modification date for the XML files doesnt change. However,  `setObj_toXML` works fine when is called in `set_processObj`.

Comment: Then I wonder, does `get_LastUpdate_SheetRange` return anything?

Comment: It does, but only if `$this = $this.getObj_fromXML()`  inside of `get_LastUpdate_SheetRange` is commented